# how to exclude some reg pattern

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression to search out all "http" string and replace it with "https", I use following Reg expression:

```
\bhttp\b
```

but some results are not what I want, for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

so how can I exclude this?
I want to use notepad++ to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately if the data is not structured, and you have to string filter, then you need to assess the whole dataset, and decide if this is to be done as a once-off, or if you need a system to do frequently perform the same type of operation, on similar documents, or very different documents, etc..

If it is only the meta line example you want to exclude:

- You can try `\bhttp[^-]\b`

If all relevant instances of `http` are in a certain format, i.e. `href="http`:

- Then you could just be more specific with the context.  i.e. `\b(?<=href=")http\b`

The latter example will match using `href="` but not include it in the replace operation